# Найти абзацы, удалить все теги, оставив только название

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения, обработка-ошибок

Задание:

> С помощью регулярного выражения написать программу, которая ищет в
> тексте все абзацы, удаляет теги и оставляет только текст:

> Было: `<p> текст </p>`
> Стало: `текст`

Попытка решения:

```
import re 

input_filename = "../progr.txt"
result_filename = "../result.txt"

input_file = open(input_filename, mode = 'r', encoding = "utf-8")
resultfile = open(result_filename, mode = 'w', encoding = "utf-8")
mytext = input_file.read()

lookfor = r'^(?:(?!^$)[\s\S])+$'
results = re.findall(lookfor, mytext)
rst = re.sub('^(?:(?!^$)[\\s\\S])+$','', results)
print(rst)
```

Получаю ошибку:

> expected string or bytes-like object

Comment: На какой строке ошибка? Приведите пример данных.

Comment: И вы читаете файл в двоичном виде

Comment: @CrazyElf Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Users/markh/Desktop/bot/четверта.py", line 15, in <module>
    rst = re.sub('^(?:(?!^$)[\\s\\S])+$','', results)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\re.py", line 208, in sub
    return _compile(pattern, flags).sub(repl, string, count)
TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object

Comment: `re.sub(...)` ожидает строку в качестве третьего параметра, вы же передаете список - `results`. На подобные вопросы (по обработке данных) зачастую практически невозможно дать полезный ответ если в вопросе отсутствуют примеры входных и выходных данных!

Comment: Приведите пожалуйста в вопросе небольшой, но воспроизводимый пример входных данных (__в виде текста / CSV / Python кода или ссылки на файл__) и __то что вы ожидаете получить на выходе__. Также советую ознакомиться: [Как наиболее эффективно задать вопрос, связанный с обработкой и/или анализом данных (например: по Pandas / Numpy / SciPy / SciKit Learn / SQL)](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7060/)

Comment: @MaxU К примеру, было: <p>текст</p>
Стало: текст

Comment: @Maina, что это за текст - это HTML / XML??

Comment: @Maina, [вот решение](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1208656/211923) ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Решение:

```
res = re.sub(r"<p>(.*?)</p>", r"\1", text, flags=re.S)
```

пояснения регулярного выражения: `(.*?)`

- круглые скобки обозначают группу захвата ("capturing group"), которую можно использовать в части замены обращаясь к содержимому группы по его порядковому номеру - пример: `r"\1"`.
- `.` -  точка в регулярных выражениях имеет особый смысл - это шаблон для указания **любого** единичного символа
- знак `*` после точки обозначает мультипликатор, повторяющий предшествующий символ или группу ноль или более раз
- знак `?` после звездочки обозначает нежадный модификатор, указывающий что предыдущий символ/группа повторится ноль или один раз. Это нужно для того, чтобы в группу захвата попало содержимое **только одного** тега.

Таким образом выражение `re.sub(r"<p>(.*?)</p>", r"\1", text, flags=re.S)` будет заменять все найденные подстроки вида `"<p>любой текст</p>"` на содержимое тега.

PS если убрать знак вопроса из решения то в группу захвата попадет только одна подстрока от **первого** вхождения `"<p>"` до **последнего** вхождения `"</p>"`:

```
In [72]: re.sub(r"<p>(.*)</p>", r"\1", "prefix <p>first</p>, middle, <p>second</p> suffix", flags=re.S)
Out[72]: 'prefix first</p>, middle, <p>second suffix'
```

вместо:

```
In [73]: re.sub(r"<p>(.*?)</p>", r"\1", "prefix <p>first</p>, middle, <p>second</p> suffix", flags=re.S)
Out[73]: 'prefix first, middle, second suffix'
```